# Magento 1.9 Invalid block type

Tags: error, exception

I have this error that i try to solve in Magento 1.9 and would like help solving it.

```
2015-03-19T10:09:32+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid blocktype: ' in /home/******/public_html/onlineshop/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/******/public_html/onlineshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid blockty...')
#1 /home/******/public_html/onlineshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('', Array)
#2 /home/******/public_html/onlineshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('', 'product_list_to...')
#3 /home/******/public_html/onlineshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('', 'product_list_to...')
#4 /home/******/public_html/onlineshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/******/public_html/onlineshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#6 /home/******/public_html/onlineshop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(148): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#7 /home/******/public_html/onlineshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#8 /home/******/public_html/onlineshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#9 /home/******/public_html/onlineshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 /home/******/public_html/onlineshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 /home/******/public_html/onlineshop/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /home/******/public_html/onlineshop/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}
</pre>
```

The problem should be with:

```
createBlock('', 'product_list_to...')
addBlock('', 'product_list_to...')
```

Somewhere is the block type wrong for product_list_toolbar. You can find this in:

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\tag.xml
app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\catalogsearch.xml
app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\catalog.xml
```

Where the code is:

```
         <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
            </block>
            <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
        </block>
```

Am i searching in the right place? The type seems to be right.

Answer (score 1):

You're close. Note `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('', 'product_list_to...')`. The method `addBlock` takes the first argument to be the *block class* name/alias, but an empty string is being passed in.

This is also why your error message says `'Invalid blocktype: '` instead of `'Invalid blocktype: XYZ'`.

```
public function addBlock($block, $blockName)
{
    return $this->createBlock($block, $blockName);
}
```

This should give you a good start.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i have problems finding where the method picks the $block up from the toolbar block. Where does it get the empty string from?

Answer (score 1):

If you would just like to get the html. Use `$this->getChildHtml('product_list_toolbar')` in the phtml file for this page.